# Imagick extension not enabled on the browser version of php in mac mojave

Tags: homebrew, imagick, macos-mojave, apache2.4, php-7.3

I am using mac mojave with the following configuration.
Apache2 - Installed from default
phph 7.3.8 - installed from brew
imagick - installed from brew

Now the issue is that the imagick extension is not loaded on the browser version of php. When i am checking the cli version all this extensions are enabled.

I have tried to restart the apache and all

Any guess or suggestions to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`php` installed by homebrew doesn't have Imagick extension builtin. You should install the extension with `pecl` manually.

```sh
brew install imagemagick
brew install pkg-config
pecl install imagick
```

After that, check `php.ini` to make sure `extension = "imagick.so"` exist.

Comment: Also install imagemagick, if it is not already installed. Imagick needs ImageMagick.